# Extract money withdrawn from SMS sent by bank

Tags: android, sms, currency

I'm making an app for managing money. It includes entering your payments and expenses.

To make it slightly innovative I wanted to do the following -
Whenever we withdraw using a CC, we always get a message(SMS) from the bank that a certain amount has been withdrawn. I wanted my app to detect such messages, extract the number specifying amount withdrawn,save it and then subtract that from the income the user has entered in the app (his balance).

Still new to this, can any help me with the code here?

Edit - 
Sorry, but the problem is that I'm not sure how to tackle this. 
Saw something similar here - [Android - Extract text from SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113829/android-extract-text-from-sms)

But wasnt sure if that can be applied here.

This is an example of an SMS received from a bank - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sI30.jpg

What I was thinking is that searching for a string like "available balance" and extracting and saving a number that follows such a text

Comment: Please, add a sample text message received...

Comment: Please don't post a question that you haven't tried to solve. You should attempt to solve it yourself first. If you have tried, you can then include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: @RobertoTellezIbarra Image added

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Reference added

Comment: Please check this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67465208/6672373 there is complete example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can implement an automated application to do this. (Sorry, but I can't code that application since this site is not intended for that)

You need to implement a BroadcastReceiver for reading incoming messages. If you find a message containing

> BOI Star Sandesh...

then you can look for specific word (Credited, Debited), date and available balance.

Finally you could visualise those data using a chart, table, or list with transaction history.

Come here again with specific question about implementing.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank You! I was looking for someone to direct me towards getting a solution, and this definitely helps! I'll see what I can come up with and bump this thread.

Comment: You're welcome. I enjoy building this type of utility solution, but I have a lot of work for now. Please, vote up and accept my answer. Good luck, Roberto.

Comment: I have implemented a part of this, and am able to extract specific keywords from the message received as asked here initially. The problem is that the app needs to be open in the background atleast, if not running, for it to read a new message and extract the reqd info. Else, if the message is deleted before opening the app (or not running in the background), the message contents arent extracted. Its a boundary case, but something that needs to be handled. How can I do this?

Comment: Is there any link which shows all bank SMS Addess. So i can easily find bank name.

Answer (score 1):

Please check https://github.com/minimal-scouser/trny

It has a method called [getTransactionInfo](https://github.com/minimal-scouser/trny#gettransactioninfo) that returns an obj containing

```
{
  account {type: "", no: ""}
  balance: "",
  money: "",
  typeOfTransaction: ""
}
```

Example:

```js
import { getTransactionInfo } from "trny";

const message = "Dear Customer, Rs.248,759.00 is debited from A/c XXXX6791 for BillPay/Credit Card payment via Example Bank NetBanking. Call XXXXXXXX161XXX if txn not done by you";

const info = getTransactionInfo(string: string)
/*
{
    account: {type: "account", no: "6791"},
    balance: "",
    money: "248759.00",
    typeOfTransaction: "debited"
}, 
*/
```

It also has methods like

1. [getAccount](https://github.com/minimal-scouser/trny#getaccount)
2. [getMoneySpent](https://github.com/minimal-scouser/trny#getmoneyspent)
3. [getBalance](https://github.com/minimal-scouser/trny#getbalance)

This needs more testing but see if this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi, but how do i extract the sms from my messages?

Comment: Are sms and message not the same thing in this context?

Comment: thank you for getting back to me, in this context i mean how do i extract a single message for all the messages i receive on my phone?